# Nvidia graphics card model not detected on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F9Dsv000017AAsd0000380Dbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-495 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

This is when i run ubuntu-drivers devices
i use a gtx1650 and amd integrated graphics,and i dual-boot windows and ubuntu.windows detecs the graphics card just fine,but ubuntu doesnt.

```
~$ lspci -nn | egrep -i "3d|display|vga"
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1f9d] (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1638] (rev c5)
```

This is what i get when i run the command. I would like to switch the VGA from amd graphics to nvidia graphice,or disable the integrated amd graphics.

I use linux kernel 5.13.0-27-generic .

```
root@SoojinComputer:/home/soojin# lsmod | grep -i nvidia
nvidia_uvm           1036288  0
nvidia_drm             61440  12
nvidia_modeset       1150976  7 nvidia_drm
nvidia              36904960  650 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        253952  2 amdgpu,nvidia_drm
drm                   557056  19 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,nvidia,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,nvidia_drm,ttm
root@SoojinComputer:/home/soojin# lspci -nn -k | egrep -i "3d|display|vga" -A3
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1f9d] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380d]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
--
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1638] (rev c5)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3801]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Comment: What is your Linux kernel version?

Comment: 5.13.0-27-generic

Comment: What do you have for `lsmod | grep -i nvidia`  and `lspci -nn -k | egrep -i "3d|display|vga" -A3`? Please edit your question and add info to it.

Comment: yes, i added them

Comment: I see. Drivers are normally loaded, so it should work. Let's wait for comments/answers from other users.

Comment: What happens if you type `nvidia-smi` in the terminal? In `Nvidia X Server Settings` app, what is it set for in the **PRIME Profiles** tab?